# Convert array of comma-separated strings to a flat array of individual values

Tags: php, arrays, string, csv, delimited

I need to change an array of comma-delimited integers into an array of individual numbers.

Sample input:

```
[
    '1,24,5',
    '4',
    '88, 12, 19, 6'
]
```

Desired result:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 24
   [2] => 5
   [3] => 4
   [4] => 88
   [5] => 12
   [6] => 19
   [7] => 6
)
```

Comment: looping over the original array, exploding each entry and merging the results all together into a new array (possibly with a trim for good measure)

Answer (score 4):

```
$data = preg_split('/,\s*/', implode(',', $data));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

```
$result = array();
foreach($inputArray as $value) {
    $result = array_merge($result, explode(',', $value));
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/private/64167cfe889bbf)

---

Original answer:

```
$arr = array('1,24,5', 4, '88, 12, 19, 6');
$result = array();

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if(strpos($value, ',') !== FALSE) {
        $result = array_merge($result, explode(',', $value));
        $result = array_map('trim', $result); // trim whitespace
    }
    else {
        $result[] = trim($value);
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array(
  '1,24,5',
  '4',
  '88,12,19,6'
);


$new_arr = explode(',',implode(',',array_values($old_arr)));


Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 24
  [2] => 5
  [3] => 4
  [4] => 88
  [5] => 12
  [6] => 19
  [7] => 6
)
```